# Windows Dns cache list in python

Tags: python, windows, dns

Hi i wanted get the DNS chase list form windows in python.
I want to import the ipconfig /displaydns data into my python file but have no idea where to start .I have looked a lot on the internet but couldn't find any examples

Comment: "I have looked a lot on the internet " Where and what? What did you try exactly? You should at least try to provide some code. For DNS in Python, `dnspython.org` is your default go to route. `resolver.resolve` does use the OS provided search list. It might not be exposed as API but studying this source code may give you hints.

Comment: i looked at Dnspython.org but the documentation wasn't very good mabey i didn't understant it but i look at it for a long time with no lead on what i schould do next

Comment: "what i schould do next" Maybe start by really explaining your problem, why you need that list? What exact Python code did you try anyway? You shouldn't expect anyone here giving you a full fledged program instead of you working on it. I feel the DNSPython documentation to be very exhaustive and good, what do you find not good in it exactly?

Comment: i dont aspect people to give me a full program. what i do aspect is help to get me started with what i could use for such an program because i dont understant dns fully and there by the documentation of it is just a learning project for me and i've looked for videos that explane what i'm looking for haven't found any